# How do I change the colour of an image in the canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically I want to change the colour of an image acording to a bool, but everything I tried made the whole canvas change colour together with it. Any solutions on how to limit it to the omject with the script?

here is the script that I am curently using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

  public class VentCor : MonoBehaviour
 {
static bool fechado;

void Update()
{
    if (fechado == true) 
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().material.color = new Color(255, 0, 0 ); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().material.color = new Color(0, 255, 0);
        
    }

    
}

public void fecha()
{
    fechado = !fechado;


}
```

Comment: `gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().color`

Comment: If you use a custom shader, make sure using `_Color` in the fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the `Canvas` is also changing is that you are not changing the color of the object, but the [`material`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.html) color of the object. As objects share `materials` and you are not instancing it in your code, you are effectively changing the default `material` for every UI object to the color you are setting. By changing this default `material`, all objects that use this `material`, which by default is all UI objects, will change color.

Here is your old code with the proper call to the `color` field instead of setting the `material` color.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class VentCor : MonoBehaviour
{
    static bool fechado;
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (fechado == true) 
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().color = new Color(255, 0, 0 ); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().color = new Color(0, 255, 0);
            
        }
    }
    
    public void fecha()
    {
        fechado = !fechado;
    }
}
```

I also attached a snippet where I made a few edits. I wrote out why I made each change.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(RawImage))]
public class VentCor : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField] private RawImage img = null;
    
    private bool fechado;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        if(img == null)
            img = GetComponent<RawImage>();
    }
    
    public void SetFechado(bool b)
    {
        fechado = b; 
        UpdateImageColor();
    }
    
    public void fecha()
    {
        fechado = !fechado;
        UpdateImageColor();
    }
    
    private void UpdateImageColor()
    {
        img.color = fechado ? Color.red : Color.green;   
    }
}
```

Firstly, I removed the `static` accessor for your variable `Fechado` and made it private. Instead, I created a public `setter` method `SetFechado` that takes a `bool` parameter. Instead of directly setting the variable, you can now set it by calling the method and passing in the `bool` state.

```
private bool fechado;
```

Next, I stored the `RawImage` component instead of using `GetComponent` as caching components is performantly better if you intend to set the color often enough.

```
[SerializeField] private RawImage img = null;
    
private bool fechado;
    
private void Start()
{
    if(img == null)
        img = GetComponent<RawImage>();
}
```

After this, I removed the `Update` method as the only time you need to make a check for what the `bool` is, is when it changes. As I had removed the static keyword from the variable, you now need to add a `setter` method to allow to set the `bool` from outside the script.

```
public void SetFechado(bool b)
{
    fechado = b; 
    UpdateImageColor();
}

private void UpdateImageColor()
{
    img.color = fechado ? Color.red : Color.green;   
}
```

The final change I made was to use the [`predefined colors`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) `red` and `green`. If you ever would like to change the colors to a color Unity does not predefined, you can change the code back to creating a new `Color` struct. I would advise creating the `Color` at compile time or as a `SerializedField` to define it in the inspector.

Comment: Not sure about the UI element classes but e.g. for `Renderet.material` the property actually returns a new **instance** of the material .. I would think that `RawImage.material` behaves the same way .. might be wrong though

Comment: @derHugo I believe that is usually the case. I tested the set up OP has and sure enough, setting the color from code as they are will change all UI element's color. I am not sure if this is a special case with `Default UI Material` or specifically with `RawImage.material`. I also had tried caching the returned `Material` from the call as it usually is instanced and setting the color after. However, I got the same result.

Comment: @Nyxie Glad to have helped! If this post answered your question, you can close the question by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer. It lets others know there is a working solution to your question.